# Missing characters in Greek output due to `\ttfamily`

Tags: babel, greek, typewriter, libertine

Unfortunately the next question in the series [ASCII text set in Greek script when using \usepackage[greek]{babel}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548584/44119) / [Missing characters in output due to `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548761/44119)

When we have a MWE like:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}

00027         printf({"{}JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\(\backslash\)n"{}}); \par
00027         printf({"{}Just a print statement\(\backslash\)n"{}}); \par
00028         printf({"{}Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\(\backslash\)n"{}}); \par

  \normalfont\ttfamily%
{00027         printf({"{}JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\(\backslash\)n"{}});}\par
{00027         printf({"{}Just a print statement\(\backslash\)n"{}});}\par
{00028         printf({"{}Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\(\backslash\)n"{}});}\par
  \normalfont%
  \normalsize%

\end{document}
```

The output is like:

[image]

we see that in the Momospaced part a number of Greek characters are missing, how to fix this?

**Edit**
I used the advice from @Mico to use `\setmonofont{Noto Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` (I actually copied his entire code), but got a strange output:

[image]

Comment: You need to use `\setmonofont{<font>}` with a font that supports Greek.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I place `\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono} ` just beneath `\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}` I get all square boxes with a question mark in it (so character not found) in the last monospaced line. Any suggestion for a font / how I should improve my code?

Comment: That's because `Libertinus Mono` doesn't feature the required greek letters.

Comment: @Mico I just looked in the log file and see `Missing character: There is no Λ in font Libertinus Mono Regular/OT:script=latn
;language=dflt;!` for a number of characters, but no clue from my side. Any suggestions for a Monospaced font with Greek characters?

Comment: @albert - Please see the answer I just posted. I chose `Noto Mono`, but there have got to be other suitable monospaced fonts out there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A monospaced font that provides the required Greek characters is `Noto Mono`. There must be many other suitable monospaced fonts out there.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
\obeylines % to avoid having to type all those \par directives...
00027         printf({"{}JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\(\backslash\)n"{}}); 
00027         printf({"{}Just a print statement\(\backslash\)n"{}}); 
00028         printf({"{}Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\(\backslash\)n"{}}); 
\ttfamily
00027         printf({"{}JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\(\backslash\)n"{}});
00027         printf({"{}Just a print statement\(\backslash\)n"{}});
00028         printf({"{}Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\(\backslash\)n"{}});
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your output looks nice, my output looks horrible (please see edited question).

Comment: Possibly `Scale=MatchUppercase` is better.

Comment: @egreg unfortunately same sort of output (I tried it beforehand).

Comment: Looks like `\setmonofont{Courier New}` solves my problem for this small problem (for other outputs we already use `Courier`). I'm going to test it in the larger code base.

Comment: @albert - Glad you found a mono font -- Courier New -- that meets your needs. As I wrote up front in my answer, "There must be many other suitable monospaced fonts out there." :-)

Comment: The help I got from the forum is very valuable, gives me insights and pointers to formulate searches with other possibilities / additional information.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a monospaced font that supports Greek. Since your document is in sans serif, a choice might be DejaVu Sans Mono, which is also included in TeX Live. Since monospaced fonts tend to look bigger than they are, I applied a scale factor; experiment until you find the right value, but look at the screen from a distance.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=0.8]

\begin{document}

00027         printf("JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\textbackslash n"); \par
00027         printf("Just a print statement\textbackslash n"); \par
00028         printf("Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\textbackslash n"); \par

\begin{verbatim}
00027   printf("JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\n");
00027   printf("Just a print statement\n");
00028   printf("Λίστα Δοκιμαστικών\n");
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Also, rather than using complicated constructions, `verbatim` is handier for such objects.

[image]

Comment: With the DejaVu font I cannot create the pdf file, getting some "Driver error" but no further information and the pdf is corrupt beyond repair. I just found `\setmonofont{Courier New}` that looks like to solve my problem for this small problem (for other outputs we already use `Courier`). I'm going to test it in the larger code base.

Comment: When using the `\begin{verbatim}` construct I get `dvipdfmx:fatal: This font using the "seac" command for accented characters...`, but anyway "verbatim" construct might be a good construct but seen the fact that it is in generated code, that is also used for other output languages, I'm a bit reluctant to change it from "ttfamily" to "verbatim"

Answer (score 2):

The Computer Modern Unicode fonts are clones of Knuth’s Computer Modern, like Latin Modern is, that contain Greek.  So you could use

```
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

A good tip for solving bugs like this is to add `\tracinglostchars=2` to the top of the file.  Then TeX will tell you if the font you selected does not contain a character you’re using.  By default, it silently logs a warning message to the `.log` file.

Comment: The CMU fonts works nicely. I got the impression from the answer that also "Latin Modern" would work, so I tried to set `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}` and `\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}` but this resulted again in the missing characters (gave a nice opportunity to test the `\tracinglostchars=2`).